# correct use of lambda function with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, ta-lib

I want to apply a function to a DataFrame for creating a new dataframe with mean values using lambda, and I'm getting this error:

TypeError: ("Argument 'real' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Series)", u'occurred at index 2018-01-02 00:00:00')

here is my data:

```
  AA        AAPL          FB         GOOG        TSLA  
Date                                                                     
2018-01-02  55.169998  168.987320  181.419998  1065.000000  320.529999   
2018-01-03  54.500000  168.957886  184.669998  1082.479980  317.250000   
2018-01-04  54.700001  169.742706  184.330002  1086.400024  314.619995   
2018-01-05  54.090000  171.675278  186.850006  1102.229980  316.579987   
2018-01-08  55.000000  171.037628  188.279999  1106.939941  336.410004   
2018-01-09  54.200001  171.018005  187.869995  1106.260010  333.690002
```

and this is what i'm trying so far:

```
data = pd.read_csv('help.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
sma20 = data.apply(lambda x: ta.SMA(x, 20), axis=0)
print(sma20.tail())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In more recent versions of pandas, you can supply a `raw=True` argument if you want `apply` to pass an `ndarray` to your function.

```
# data.apply(lambda x: ta.SMA(x, 20), axis=0, raw=True)
# Same as,
data.apply(ta.SMA, axis=0, raw=True, args=(20, ))
```

PS: you don't need the `lambda`.

Comment: done! wrong axis. sma20 = data.apply(lambda x: ta.SMA(x, 3), axis=0, raw=True,)
Thank you.